# Changing global variable using stat.c

Tags: c, debugging, linux-kernel, global-variables

I am trying to print logs dynamically. What I have done is I have a debug variable which I set in my own `stat_my.c` file.  Below is `show_stat` function.

```
extern int local_debug_lk;   

static int show_stat(struct seq_file *p, void *v)
{
        int temp=0;
        if(local_debug_lk == 0)
        {
                seq_printf(p,"local_debug_lk=0, enabling,int_num=%d\n",int_num);
                local_debug_lk=1;
        }
        else
        {
        seq_printf(p,"local_debug_lk=:%d,int_num=%d\n",local_debug_lk,int_num);
                while(temp<int_num){
                seq_printf(p,"%d\n",intr_list_seq[temp]);
                temp++;
                }

                local_debug_lk=0;
                int_num=0;

        }

        return 0;
}
```

### Driver file

```
int local_debug_lk, int_num;

  isr_root(...){
/*
logic to extract IRQ number, saved in vect variable
*/

                     if(local_debug_lk && (int_num < 50000)){
                        intr_list_seq[int_num]=vect;
                         int_num++;
     }
```

What I expect is when I do "`cat /proc/show_stat`", first it will enable `local_debug_lk` flag and whenever an interrupt occurs in driver file, it will be stored in `intr_list_seq[]` array. and when I do "`cat /proc/stat_my`" second time, it should print IRQ sequence and disable IRQ recording by setting `local_debug_lk=0`.

But…what's happening is, I am always getting 
"`local_debug_lk=0, enabling,int_num=0`" log on `cat`; i.e. `local_debug_lk` is always zero; it never gets enabled.

Also, when my driver is not running, it works fine!
On two consecutive "`cat /proc/stat_my`", first value is set to 1 and then 0 again.

Is it possible my driver is not picking latest updated value of `local_debug_lk` variable?

Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please make an [mcve] with all parts, i.e. at least both files.

Comment: I don't see how int_num is getting linked in show_stat. There is no extern declaration. Do you have a local static int_num in your stat_my.c file?

Comment: int_num and intr_list_seq both are extern in stat file, just not mentioned in here :), i have posted relevant code here. and issue is with local_debug_lk not getting updated in driver file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be **more** calls to `.show` function than readings from the file (with `cat /proc/show_stat`). Moreover underlying system expects **stable results** from `.show`: if called with the same parameters, the function should print the same information to the `seq_file`.

Because of that, *switching* a flag in the `.show` function has a *little sence*, and making the function's output *dependent* on this flag is simply **wrong**.

Generally, changing any kernel state when a file is *read* is not what expected by the user. It is better to use *write* functionality for that.

---

Function `.show` actually prints information into temporary *kernel* buffer. If everything goes OK, information from the buffer is transmitted into *user* buffer and eventually is printed by `cat`. But if kernel buffer is *too small*, information printed into it is **discarded**. In that case underlying system allocates bigger buffer, and call `.show` again.

Also, `.show` is rerun if *user* buffer is too small to accomodate all information printed.

Comment: If this method is wrong,please suggest any other way, using which i can dynamically enable/disable logs in kernel, thanks in advance  :)

Comment: As I said in the answer, you are better implement `.write` function for the file, which will set/unset your flag according to the string written. That is, `echo 1 > /proc/stat_my` will set the flag, and `echo 0 > /proc/stat_my` will unset it.

Comment: @lokesh, Why do not want to use the default debug mechanism provided by kernel, where you can selectively enable a print message. More information here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try both suggestions :)